# How to transform dynamic query parameter object to Sequelize Operators (Javascript Symbols)

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a dynamic `filter` method that passes through properties that I need to filter my `Sequelize` query with. For example, I might want to filter a list of `Cars` by a certain price range and a manufacture date. Resulting in a client query that would look like this:

```
const response = await this.get('cars', {
    price: {
        gt: 80000
        lt: 1200000
    },
    year: 2019
})
```

The query parameters would be serialized, sent over to my server, and then decoded back to object form. In this query I would need to make use of Sequelize's `[Op.gt]` and `[Op.lt]` symbols since I need to filter by price range. How can I dynamically convert my objects to look like this:

```
const Op = require('sequelize').Op;

const whereParams = {
    price: {
        [Op.gt]: 80000,
        [Op.lt]: 120000
    },
    year: 2019
}
```

So that I can use them within my `where` property:

```
router.get('cars', (req, res) => {
    Car.findAll({
        where: whereParams
    }).then((cars) => {
        res.status(200).send(cars);
    })
})
```

I can't simply hard code the Sequelize objects because this filter parameter is dynamic, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At least for your simple example, [json-transormer-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-transformer-node) could get the job done.

First, make sure the Sequelize object has operator aliases:

```
 ... 
 dialect: 'mysql',
 operatorsAliases: { $lt: Op.lt, $gt: Op.gt},
 define: {
 ...
```

Then, set up a transformation:

```
const nodeJsonTransformer = require('json-transformer-node');

var carFilter = {
    price: {
        gt: 80000
        lt: 1200000
    }
}

var transformation = {
    mapping : {
      item : {
        price : {
          $gt : 'price.gt',
          $lt : 'price.lt'
        }
      }
    }
 };

var whereValues = nodeJsonTransformer.transform(carFilter, transformation);
Car.findAll( {where: whereValues})
```

The generated query should include `WHERE price > 8000 AND price < 12000`.  Caveat: this could be cumbersome if you have a complicated filter...